# Can't access maven profile properties via java

Tags: java, maven, junit-jupiter

I am trying to configure maven profiles for junit 5 tests. The problem is can't read profile properties.
Here is how i set up profiles

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <properties>
            <profile.id>dev</profile.id>
            <RestAssured.TSIDBaseURI>http://url/dev</RestAssured.TSIDBaseURI>
        </properties>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <id>test</id>
         <properties>
            <profile.id>test</profile.id>
            <RestAssured.TSIDBaseURI>http://url/test</RestAssured.TSIDBaseURI>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Then i configured buid resourses

```
 <build>

    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

Then i created **config.properties** in src/test/resources directory like this

```
RestAssured.TSIDBaseURI=${RestAssured.TSIDBaseURI}
```

Finally i do setup method

```
@BeforeAll
    @Step(value = "Setup")
    static void setUp() throws IOException {
        Properties loadedProperties = new Properties();
        InputStream resourceAsStream = TSIDBase.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties");
        loadedProperties.load(resourceAsStream);
        RestAssured.baseURI = loadedProperties.getProperty("RestAssured.TSIDBaseURI");
        System.out.println("URI = " + RestAssured.baseURI);
    }
```

Unfortunately i am always getting **RestAssured.baseURI**  =**${RestAssured.TSIDBaseURI}** value for base URI and i can't see why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed build directory from resourses to testResources and it worked

```
<testResources>
    <testResource>
        <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
    </testResource>
</testResources>
```